# Search bar not working in Swift 4 IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, searchbar

I have implemented a search bar to search for users, but nothing shows up in the table view when I search for something. I have attached a picture of my view controller below.

View Controller:

[image: View Controller]

This view controller shows a list of all the users and the search bar is supposed to help the user find a username.

```
import UIKit

class FindFriendsViewController: UIViewController {

var users = [User]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var searchItem = [String]()
var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.rowHeight = 71

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    UserService.usersExcludingCurrentUser { [unowned self] (users) in
        self.users = users

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
extension FindFriendsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchItem.count
    } else {
        return users.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FindFriendsCell") as! FindFriendsCell
```

//        let user = users[indexPath.row]

```
    var usernamesArr = [String]()
    for user in users {
        usernamesArr.append(user.username)
    }

    if searching {
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchItem[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = usernamesArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        configure(cell: cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    return cell
}

func configure(cell: FindFriendsCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username
    cell.followButton.isSelected = user.isFollowed
}
```

}

```
extension FindFriendsViewController: FindFriendsCellDelegate {
func didTapFollowButton(_ followButton: UIButton, on cell: FindFriendsCell) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    followButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    let followee = users[indexPath.row]

    FollowService.setIsFollowing(!followee.isFollowed, fromCurrentUserTo: followee) { (success) in
        defer {
            followButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        guard success else { return }

        followee.isFollowed = !followee.isFollowed
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

}

```
extension FindFriendsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    var usernamesArr = [String]()
    for user in users {
        usernamesArr.append(user.username)
    }
    searchItem = usernamesArr.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
    searching = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking about different problems that may occur in your code. You need to set the search bar delegate and the search Result Updater:

```html
yourSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
yourSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
```

If you don't have a controller, but directly the search bar:

```html
yourSearchBar.delegate = self
yourSearchBar.searchResultsUpdater = self
```

And this as your delegate:

```html
extension MasterViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
  // MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
  }
}

extension MasterViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
  // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
  }
```

Or maybe you are missing something like updating. Check the data's path excluding the problem one for time. First, you enter the text inside the search bar, after that check in the code where the text goes and what happens. Did you update the table view when search bar is in end editing status?

If it doesn't help you, check this wonderful tutorial which I followed times ago: [Search Bar iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thank you! I will look into the tutorial and see if that code you provided works.

Answer (score 0):

try for search username using this method to filter

```
searchItem = users.filter({ (objUser) -> Bool in
                return (objUser.username?.lowercased() ?? "").starts(with: searchBar.text!.trim().lowercased())
            })
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi. It says "Value of type 'String' has no member 'trim'"

Comment: No but value is not filter according string from username so.